# How does "-a" option for git commits write commit messages?

Tags: git, command-line-interface

I messed up a `git commit` command. First of all I used the `-a` option instead of the `--amend` option. I also misspelled the `--amend` option.

```
C:\Users\Slew\Documents\my-repo>git commit -ammend -m "fix links in default layout"
[main 97328ff] mend
 2 files changed, 61 insertions(+), 8 deletions(-)
```

When I look at the commit history in my repository on GitHub, I see a commit called `mend` with three dots next to it. If I click the three dots, it reveals another message, which is the commit message I originally intended - `fix links in default layout`.

How has the `-a` option actually named this commit and what happened to that extra letter "m" which I accidentally added?

Comment: [-a
--all
Tell the command to automatically stage files that have been modified and deleted, but new files you have not told Git about are not affected.](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit) followed by a `-m` with the argument `mend`.

Comment: Which shell were you using to type this command?

Comment: @mkrieger1 I was using command prompt in windows.

Comment: @mkrieger1 Shouldn't matter. Options `-a -m` are interpreted by the option parser built into `git.exe`.

Comment: The short answer is, `-am` is shorthand for `-a -m`, where the `mend` following the `m` was interpreted as argument to `-m`. The details are specific to how cmd interprets spaces and quotes, I guess.

Comment: @phd Okay, I would have thought the same command would have given an error, or be interpreted differently, in *sh (can't check right now).

Comment: @mkrieger1 No, why? Option `-m` can be repeated, `git commit` collects the strings and add all of them (separated by empty lines) to the commit message.

Comment: @phd Interesting. I never tried that.

Comment: @mkrieger1 [If multiple -m options are given, their values are concatenated as separate paragraphs.](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit#Documentation/git-commit.txt--mltmsggt). So the command above is `git commit -a -m mend -m "fix links in default layout"`. It produces commit message "mend\n\nfix links in default layout"

Comment: wow, it's crazy that you can pack multiple options together, plus their value, like that. I would have expect `-a` and `-m` to not be packable together given  `-m` takes a value. This is very surprising behaviour indeed, but it's also nice to know, since I often use `-a` and `-m` together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`-am` is shorthand for `-a -m`, where the `mend` following the `m` was interpreted as argument to `-m`.

Furthermore, option `-m` can be repeated, `git commit` collects the strings and add all of them (separated by empty lines) to the commit message (see https://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit#Documentation/git-commit.txt--mltmsggt).

So the command above is `git commit -a -m mend -m "fix links in default layout"`.